# Audio data preprocessing in Machine Learning

Tags: audio, classification, fault

I am facing problem in loading an audio dataset. can anyone help me in getting that .
I have done it at some extent but then some errors start occuring . As I load a dataset then after it shows that this is a directory  error. someone please hepl me getting out of it.

I tried to load the file. and then I start preprocessing of it, while preprocessing it I load the file again then it shows this is a directory error .